# Unable to connect elasticsearch-opendistro with kibana

Tags: docker, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am trying to connect a `amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:0.9.0` with `docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.0.1` below is my docker compose. I new to elastic stack,

```
version: '3'

services:
  application:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:0.9.0
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=cluster
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.0.1
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://application:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net


volumes:
  data:

networks:
  odfe-net:
```

When I run the docker file I'm seeing the following error:

`{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-14T14:23:21Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://application:9200/"}`

Has anyone tried this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-unable-to-revive-connection-no-living-connections/165745/4
Or there several possible problems:
1) no definition of **container_name** in application with value "application"
2) you're trying to connect incompatible versions of Kibana (7.0.1) and ES (opendistro 0.9.0 => bare 6.7.1)